# Android permission getting rejected when asking for multiple permissions

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I need to ask the user for GPS and filesystem permissions in two separate requests.

**Expected behaviour:** The app shows request for GPS permissions, and after user makes their decision, app will show filesystem permission request and let user decide again.

**Actual behaviour:** Only request for GPS permission is shown, and filesystem permissions are automatically rejected without showing any dialog.

**Target Android version:** 5.0 and higher (API 21+)

Could someone please tell me how to fix this? Thank you in advance!

My code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    checkLocationPermissions();
    checkLoggingPermissions();

    ...
    ...
}

private void checkLoggingPermissions() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Requesting filesystem permissions from user");

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                    {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    FrontendConstants.PERMISSION_FILESYSTEM_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        else {
            LoggingService.init();
        }
    }
    else {
        LoggingService.init();
    }
}

private void checkLocationPermissions() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Requesting GPS permissions from user");

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET
            }, FrontendConstants.PERMISSION_GPS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        else {
            locationService = LocationService.getInstance(this);
        }
    }
    else {
        locationService = LocationService.getInstance(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                   String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if(FrontendConstants.PERMISSION_GPS_REQUEST_CODE == requestCode) {
        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "+++ User accepted GPS permission request");
            locationService = LocationService.getInstance(this);
        }
        else {
            Log.e(TAG, "--- User rejected GPS permission request");
        }
    }

    if(FrontendConstants.PERMISSION_FILESYSTEM_REQUEST_CODE == requestCode) {
        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "+++ User accepted filesystem permission request");
            LoggingService.init();
        }
        else {
            Log.e(TAG, "--- User rejected filesystem permission request");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should ask the next permission, when the first one is accepted or rejected

Comment: You should only call `requestPermissions` once for both permissions. Also you don't need to request `Manifest.permission.INTERNET` since it's "safe" permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have solved the problem using your advices. My approach is now to ask for all permissions in one request, and then analyze the results in `onRequestPermissionsResult`.

To do that, I have created PermissionsHelper class:

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

public class PermissionsHelper {
    private String[] permissions;
    private int[] grantResults;

    public PermissionsHelper(String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        this.permissions = permissions;
        this.grantResults = grantResults;
    }

    public boolean isPermissionGranted(String permission) {
        final int length = permissions.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if(permissions[i].equals(permission)) {
                return grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            }
        }

        // if permission wasn't found, we weren't even asking for it, so we consider it
        // as granted
        return true;
    }

    public boolean arePermissionsGranted(String ... permissions) {
        for(String permission : permissions) {
            if(!isPermissionGranted(permission)) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then I do this in my Activity, and it seems to work perfectly:

```
private void requestPermissions() {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    });
}

private void requestPermissions(String[] permissions) {
    List<String> notGranted = new ArrayList<>();

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        for(String permission : permissions) {
            if(checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                notGranted.add(permission);
            }
        }

        if(!notGranted.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, notGranted.toArray(new String[0]),
                    FrontendConstants.PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if(FrontendConstants.PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE == requestCode) {
        PermissionsHelper helper = new PermissionsHelper(permissions, grantResults);

        if(helper.isPermissionGranted(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "+++ User accepted filesystem permission request");
        }
        else {
            Log.e(TAG, "--- User rejected filesystem permission request");
        }

        if(helper.arePermissionsGranted(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "+++ User accepted GPS permission request");
        }
        else {
            Log.e(TAG, "--- User rejected GPS permission request");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would do this in one request, to simplify things for the user and for you.

That being said, to get the flow that you are seeking, call `checkLoggingPermissions()` from two places:

1. From `checkLocationPermissions()`, if the user already has granted those from some past run of your app (i.e., in the branches where you have `locationService = LocationService.getInstance(this);`)
2. From `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, if the user just granted the location permissions

And, [as Pawel mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55936067/android-permission-getting-rejected-when-asking-for-multiple-permissions#comment98524748_55936067), remove `Manifest.permission.INTERNET`, as it is a `normal` permission and does not need runtime verification.

Comment: Hmm, thank you for advices. Just one question.. Is it ok to ask for all permissions every time the app starts even if they have already been granted?

Comment: @Firzen: If by "OK" you mean "will it work?", yes. However, even if the user granted the permission previously, if you ask for it again, the user gets the dialog again. Hence, in general, I do not recommend asking for permissions that you already hold.

Comment: Thank you. I have tested it, ant it doesn't show the dialog again for already granted permissions. But I will take your advice to not do that. :-)

Comment: @Firzen: "I have tested it, ant it doesn't show the dialog again for already granted permissions" -- it is possible they changed this in newer versions of Android, or that the `ActivityCompat` stuff now filters out permissions that you were already granted. At the system level, back when runtime permissions were introduced in Android 6.0, it *definitely* would display the dialogs even if you already held the permissions.